# Find missing attribute table - Mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm cleaning up my database for sphinx indexing and there is a recurring bug that is noticeable in my data that I'm running through.

To keep this applicable to everyone else, I'll try my best to keep this conceptual rather than personal.

I have a table of *attributes* with numeric values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... etc.

I have a table of *assets*.
Assets have a 1 to many relation with attributes.

To handle the 1:N relationship we have a table to handle the relation called *asset_items*.

Each asset will hold 3 attributes: 1 2 & 3.

## Attributes

```
id |  value
___|________
1  |  month
2  |  day
3  |  year
```

## Assets

```
id | owner_id
___|_________
1  | 512
```

## Asset Items

A good set of data would something like this:

```
id | asset_id | attribute_id | attribute_value
___|__________|______________|_________________
1  | 1        | 1            | March
2  | 1        | 2            | 2
3  | 1        | 3            | 2015
```

Because of my bug I'm looking for an example similar to all the Assets that are missing an attribute_id of 2. Ex:

```
id  | asset_id  | attribute_id | attribute_value
____|___________|______________|_________________
45  | 22        | 1            | October
47  | 22        | 3            | 1996
```

My SQL so far is:

```
select *
from asset_items
group by attribute_id  
having count(attribute_id = 2) = 0
```

But unfortunately that is returning nothing. The correct SQL should return > 500 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select asset_id
from asset_items
group by asset_id  
having sum(case when attribute_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: It returned less rows than I was expecting, but I believe that's because I previously cleaned most of them up manually as I was running through them. I understand your answer as I read it, but man I would have never come up with that on my own. I really appreciate your answer and I'm glad you could understand my example.